# T-SQL Syntax Error nonexistent (or, at least, I can't see it, and intellisense too) but still notified

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've got a script which clones a database schema (the tables) and adds some columns to keep track of data changes (we often receive data from legacy ERPs), this script creates some stored procedures to check for the changes in the data, it always worked like a charm but today after launching it on a test database it gave me an error:

> *Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure COMPUTE_AGENT, Line 9
>
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'*

This is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[COMPUTE_AGENT] (@Debug INT = 0)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Actions TABLE (IUD VARCHAR(100))

    INSERT INTO @Actions (IUD)
    SELECT IUD
    FROM (
        MERGE [frontier].[AGENT] AS [Destination]
        USING [dbo].[AGENT] AS [Source]
            ON [Destination].[AgentCode] = [Source].[AgentCode]
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
            THEN
                INSERT (
                    [AgentCode]
                    ,[Name]
                    ,[PersonalTaxCode]
                    ,[VatNumber]
                    ,[Commission]
                    ,[Address]
                    ,[City]
                    ,[ZipCode]
                    ,[Province]
                    ,[Region]
                    ,[Country]
                    ,[Phone]
                    ,[CellPhone]
                    ,[FAX]
                    ,[EMail]
                    ,[Web]
                    ,[LastEditDate]
                    ,[CHECKSUM]
                    ,[SyncroLED]
                    ,[SyncroPS]
                    )
                VALUES (
                    [Source].[AgentCode]
                    ,[Source].[Name]
                    ,[Source].[PersonalTaxCode]
                    ,[Source].[VatNumber]
                    ,[Source].[Commission]
                    ,[Source].[Address]
                    ,[Source].[City]
                    ,[Source].[ZipCode]
                    ,[Source].[Province]
                    ,[Source].[Region]
                    ,[Source].[Country]
                    ,[Source].[Phone]
                    ,[Source].[CellPhone]
                    ,[Source].[FAX]
                    ,[Source].[EMail]
                    ,[Source].[Web]
                    ,[Source].[LastEditDate]
                    ,BINARY_CHECKSUM([Source].[AgentCode], [Source].[Name], [Source].[PersonalTaxCode], [Source].[VatNumber], [Source].[Commission], [Source].[Address], [Source].[City], [Source].[ZipCode], [Source].[Province], [Source].[Region], [Source].[Country], [Source].[Phone], [Source].[CellPhone], [Source].[FAX], [Source].[EMail], [Source].[Web], [Source].[LastEditDate])
                    ,GETDATE()
                    ,0
                    )
        WHEN MATCHED
            AND [Destination].[CHECKSUM] <> BINARY_CHECKSUM([Source].[AgentCode], [Source].[Name], [Source].[PersonalTaxCode], [Source].[VatNumber], [Source].[Commission], [Source].[Address], [Source].[City], [Source].[ZipCode], [Source].[Province], [Source].[Region], [Source].[Country], [Source].[Phone], [Source].[CellPhone], [Source].[FAX], [Source].[EMail], [Source].[Web], [Source].[LastEditDate])
            THEN
                UPDATE
                SET [Destination].[AgentCode] = [Source].[AgentCode]
                    ,[Destination].[Name] = [Source].[Name]
                    ,[Destination].[PersonalTaxCode] = [Source].[PersonalTaxCode]
                    ,[Destination].[VatNumber] = [Source].[VatNumber]
                    ,[Destination].[Commission] = [Source].[Commission]
                    ,[Destination].[Address] = [Source].[Address]
                    ,[Destination].[City] = [Source].[City]
                    ,[Destination].[ZipCode] = [Source].[ZipCode]
                    ,[Destination].[Province] = [Source].[Province]
                    ,[Destination].[Region] = [Source].[Region]
                    ,[Destination].[Country] = [Source].[Country]
                    ,[Destination].[Phone] = [Source].[Phone]
                    ,[Destination].[CellPhone] = [Source].[CellPhone]
                    ,[Destination].[FAX] = [Source].[FAX]
                    ,[Destination].[EMail] = [Source].[EMail]
                    ,[Destination].[Web] = [Source].[Web]
                    ,[Destination].[LastEditDate] = [Source].[LastEditDate]
                    ,[Destination].[CHECKSUM] = BINARY_CHECKSUM([Source].[AgentCode], [Source].[Name], [Source].[PersonalTaxCode], [Source].[VatNumber], [Source].[Commission], [Source].[Address], [Source].[City], [Source].[ZipCode], [Source].[Province], [Source].[Region], [Source].[Country], [Source].[Phone], [Source].[CellPhone], [Source].[FAX], [Source].[EMail], [Source].[Web], [Source].[LastEditDate])
                    ,[Destination].[SyncroLED] = GETDATE()
                    ,[Destination].[SyncroPS] = 0
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
            AND [Destination].[SyncroPS] <> 1
            THEN
                UPDATE
                SET [Destination].[SyncroPS] = 1
                    ,[Destination].[SyncroLED] = GETDATE()
        OUTPUT $ACTION
        ) AS TheMerge(IUD)

    IF @Debug = 1
        SELECT IUD AS [Action]
            ,COUNT(IUD) AS [Count]
        FROM @Actions
        GROUP BY IUD
END
```

I can't really see where the error is. I tried to launch the same script on many other databases without getting errors... This is really driving me mad and I have the feeling that the problem probably is trivial and i'm really stupid because I can't find it...

Here's another auto-generated procedure which doesn't give any error (generated from another db):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[COMPUTE_Agente] (@Debug INT = 0)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Actions TABLE (IUD VARCHAR(100))

    INSERT INTO @Actions (IUD)
    SELECT IUD
    FROM (
        MERGE [frontier].[Agente] AS [Destination]
        USING [dbo].[Agente] AS [Source]
            ON [Destination].[CodiceAgente] = [Source].[CodiceAgente]
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
            THEN
                INSERT (
                    [CodiceAgente]
                    ,[Nome]
                    ,[CodiceFiscale]
                    ,[PartitaIVA]
                    ,[Provvigioni]
                    ,[Indirizzo]
                    ,[Localita]
                    ,[CAP]
                    ,[Provincia]
                    ,[Regione]
                    ,[Nazione]
                    ,[Telefono]
                    ,[Cellulare]
                    ,[Fax]
                    ,[EMail]
                    ,[SitoWeb]
                    ,[DataModifica]
                    ,[CHECKSUM]
                    ,[SyncroLED]
                    ,[SyncroPS]
                    )
                VALUES (
                    [Source].[CodiceAgente]
                    ,[Source].[Nome]
                    ,[Source].[CodiceFiscale]
                    ,[Source].[PartitaIVA]
                    ,[Source].[Provvigioni]
                    ,[Source].[Indirizzo]
                    ,[Source].[Localita]
                    ,[Source].[CAP]
                    ,[Source].[Provincia]
                    ,[Source].[Regione]
                    ,[Source].[Nazione]
                    ,[Source].[Telefono]
                    ,[Source].[Cellulare]
                    ,[Source].[Fax]
                    ,[Source].[EMail]
                    ,[Source].[SitoWeb]
                    ,[Source].[DataModifica]
                    ,BINARY_CHECKSUM([Source].[CodiceAgente], [Source].[Nome], [Source].[CodiceFiscale], [Source].[PartitaIVA], [Source].[Provvigioni], [Source].[Indirizzo], [Source].[Localita], [Source].[CAP], [Source].[Provincia], [Source].[Regione], [Source].[Nazione], [Source].[Telefono], [Source].[Cellulare], [Source].[Fax], [Source].[EMail], [Source].[SitoWeb], [Source].[DataModifica])
                    ,GETDATE()
                    ,0
                    )
        WHEN MATCHED
            AND [Destination].[CHECKSUM] <> BINARY_CHECKSUM([Source].[CodiceAgente], [Source].[Nome], [Source].[CodiceFiscale], [Source].[PartitaIVA], [Source].[Provvigioni], [Source].[Indirizzo], [Source].[Localita], [Source].[CAP], [Source].[Provincia], [Source].[Regione], [Source].[Nazione], [Source].[Telefono], [Source].[Cellulare], [Source].[Fax], [Source].[EMail], [Source].[SitoWeb], [Source].[DataModifica])
            THEN
                UPDATE
                SET [Destination].[CodiceAgente] = [Source].[CodiceAgente]
                    ,[Destination].[Nome] = [Source].[Nome]
                    ,[Destination].[CodiceFiscale] = [Source].[CodiceFiscale]
                    ,[Destination].[PartitaIVA] = [Source].[PartitaIVA]
                    ,[Destination].[Provvigioni] = [Source].[Provvigioni]
                    ,[Destination].[Indirizzo] = [Source].[Indirizzo]
                    ,[Destination].[Localita] = [Source].[Localita]
                    ,[Destination].[CAP] = [Source].[CAP]
                    ,[Destination].[Provincia] = [Source].[Provincia]
                    ,[Destination].[Regione] = [Source].[Regione]
                    ,[Destination].[Nazione] = [Source].[Nazione]
                    ,[Destination].[Telefono] = [Source].[Telefono]
                    ,[Destination].[Cellulare] = [Source].[Cellulare]
                    ,[Destination].[Fax] = [Source].[Fax]
                    ,[Destination].[EMail] = [Source].[EMail]
                    ,[Destination].[SitoWeb] = [Source].[SitoWeb]
                    ,[Destination].[DataModifica] = [Source].[DataModifica]
                    ,[Destination].[CHECKSUM] = BINARY_CHECKSUM([Source].[CodiceAgente], [Source].[Nome], [Source].[CodiceFiscale], [Source].[PartitaIVA], [Source].[Provvigioni], [Source].[Indirizzo], [Source].[Localita], [Source].[CAP], [Source].[Provincia], [Source].[Regione], [Source].[Nazione], [Source].[Telefono], [Source].[Cellulare], [Source].[Fax], [Source].[EMail], [Source].[SitoWeb], [Source].[DataModifica])
                    ,[Destination].[SyncroLED] = GETDATE()
                    ,[Destination].[SyncroPS] = 0
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
            AND [Destination].[SyncroPS] <> 1
            THEN
                UPDATE
                SET [Destination].[SyncroPS] = 1
                    ,[Destination].[SyncroLED] = GETDATE()
        OUTPUT $ACTION
        ) AS TheMerge(IUD)

    IF @Debug = 1
        SELECT IUD AS [Action]
            ,COUNT(IUD) AS [Count]
        FROM @Actions
        GROUP BY IUD
END
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no syntax error in your code. The compatibility level for your database is `SQL Server 2005 (90)` or lower. It needs to be `SQL Server 2008 (100)` or higher.

[ALTER DATABASE Compatibility Level (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx)